# Python 3.8 : Concatenate characters and display int value of unicode charcater

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, unicode, utf-8

I am trying to convert a custom string to a Unicode character and display its integer value. For example, the following line should give output as 134.

```
ord('\x86')
```

Now I want to get output differently. Let's say I want to concatenate each individual symbol i.e. *'\' , 'x', '8', '6'* and generate a string say *t*. So,

```
t = '\x86'
```

But, Python is not considering *t* as a string of length 1. How can I achieve this task?

Note: The main task is to read a file that contains a chain of Unicode characters. After reading the file, I stored the character in a list. For example

```
lst = ["\x86", "\x92", "\x83" ... ]
```

Each of the list elements is not being considered as a single character but a string of 4 characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running:

```
t=eval("\""+t+"\"")
```

To convert it.